# Are there any alternate ways other than Named Entity Recognition to extract event names from sentences?

Tags: opennlp, named-entity-recognition, information-extraction

I'm a newbie to NLP and I'm working on NER using OpenNLP. I have a sentence like " We have a dinner party today ". Here "dinner party" is an event type. Similarly consider this sentence- "we have a room reservation" here room reservation is an event type. My goal is to extract such words from sentences and label it as "Event_types" as the final output. This can be fairly achieved by creating custom NER model's by annotating sentences with proper tags in the training dataset. But the event types can be heterogeneous and random and hence it is very hard to label all possible patterns(ie. event types can be anything like "security meeting", "family function","parents teachers meeting", etc,etc,...). So I'm looking for an alternate way to achieve this problem... Immediate response would be appreciated. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two options: 1) A list-based approach where you have lists of entities you will extract from text. To solve the heterogeneous language use, one can train an embedding (e.g. Word2Vec or FastText) to identify contextually similar phrases for your list. 2) Train a custom CRF with data you have annotated (this obviously requires that you annotate bunch of sentences with corresponding tags). I guess the ideal solution really depends on the data and people's willingness to annotate it.